# how to zoom-in interface? Android development

Tags: android

In my Android application, I have an activity with three layouts: A left layout, a middle layout, and a right layout.

The right layout is the main one. I want the right layout to zoom into fullscreen when I click a button. If you have the specific code,it's better.

Thanks very much!

Comment: You're clearly assuming too much context. Is this for a website? Some kind of GUI kit? A mobile app? What language? "Zoom" is not sensible tag either.

Comment: sorry,I forgot to write the language.It's android development.The language is JAVA.

Comment: I've never developed on Android but here's some advice. Read your question and make sure that it's got all the relevant details. Otherwise, chances that you'll get an answer are quite slim.

Comment: I edited your question and tried to make it a bit easier to understand. did I get it right?

Comment: Thanks.Someone have holp me solve it.

Comment: if you got it fixed please accept the person's answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If I got your question right:**

Your button's OnClickListener should look like something like this:

```
   OnClickListener listener = OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v){
        findViewById(R.id.left_layout).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.center_layout).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
     };
```

This by itself will not get your right layout to fullscreen. You'll need to add something the below to your right layout for it to "auto fullscreen":

```
android:layout_width = "0dp";
android:layout_weight = "1";
```

if you don't do that, you'll have to resize the right layout from the "listener" above.

Comment: Sure, If you run into problems try posting some of the errors so we can get you to the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, the question is vague, but if I understand correctly, what you want to do is hide the left and center layouts when a button is clicked, so that the right layout becomes full-screen?

Without more details, it's not easy to give you a more precise answer (please post your current layout), but I would do something like:

```
// this code in your Activity:
// this method is bound to button onCLick (android:onClick="clickButton")
public void clickButton(View view) {
    findViewById(R.id.left_layout).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    findViewById(R.id.center_layout).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

And to revert back to a 3-layout display, you do the opposite (`View.VISIBLE`)

Comment: Thank you very much.You understand my meaning.I try to code it now.Maybe I will get into new trouble,please help me. Thanks again.